# CgFx compiler error "Unknown state 'VertexShader'"

Tags: opengl, shader, nvidia, cg

I' have the following CgFx file:

```
struct VertIn {
  float4 pos   : POSITION;
  float4 color : COLOR0;
};
struct VertOut {
  float4 pos   : POSITION;
  float4 color : COLOR0;
};
VertOut vert(VertIn IN) {
  VertOut OUT;
  OUT.pos     = IN.pos;
  OUT.color   = IN.color;
  OUT.color.z = 0.0f;
  return OUT;
}
struct FragIn {
  float4 color: COLOR;
};
struct FragOut {
  float4 color : COLOR;
};
FragOut frag(FragIn IN) {
  FragOut OUT;
  OUT.color = IN.color;
  OUT.color.y = 0.0f;
  return OUT;
}
struct GeomIn {
  float4 position : POSITION;
  float4 color : COLOR0;
};
TRIANGLE void geom(AttribArray<GeomIn> IN) {
  for(int i=0; i<IN.length; i++) {
    emitVertex(IN[i]);
  }
}
technique technique0 {
  pass p0 {
    VertexShader = compile gp4vp vert();    //line 47
    FragmentShader = compile gp4fp frag();  //line 48
    GeometryShader = compile gp4gp geom();  //line 49
  }
}
```

when using cgc to verify the 3 shaders, they all compile fine.

but when I try to compile the whole effect using:

```
context=cgCreateContext();
effect=cgCreateEffectFromFile(context, "my_shader.cgfx", NULL);
if(!effect) {
  printf(ygl.cgGetLastErrorString(NULL));
  printf(cgGetLastListing(context));
}
```

then I get the following errors:

```
CG ERROR : The compile returned an error.
my_shader.cgfx(47) : error C8001: Unknown state 'VertexShader'
my_shader.cgfx(48) : error C8001: Unknown state 'FragmentShader'
my_shader.cgfx(49) : error C8001: Unknown state 'GeometryShader'
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating your context, you need to call

```
cgGLRegisterStates(handle);
```

where `handle` is your CG context handle. This will register things like `VertexShader`, `PixelShader`, `FillMode`, etc. I'm not sure why those aren't registered by default, but there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

well, solved it, but don't know how. I think the compiler didn't expect CgFx because i did load a cg profile earlier, so it tried to use that one. but not sure.